# Java spring Streamable to PdfPTable

Tags: java, itext

Не знаю как сформулировать правильно, поправьте меня, пожалуйста... как результаты поиска `Streamable<Message> messages` записать в ячейки таблицы? Строк может быть сколько угодно.

```
@PostMapping("/search")
public String search (String searchsn, Map<String, Object> model) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    Streamable<Message> messages;
    if (searchsn != null && !searchsn.isEmpty()) {
        messages = messageRepo.findBySnContainingIgnoreCase(searchsn)
                .and(messageRepo.findByTextContainingIgnoreCase(searchsn))
                .and(messageRepo.findByOwnerContainingIgnoreCase(searchsn))
                .and(messageRepo.findByInvidContainingIgnoreCase(searchsn));
```

Пробовал так, но, само собой, помещается объект в ячейку:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);        
PdfPCell horizontalAlignCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.valueOf(messages),font));
        horizontalAlignCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(horizontalAlignCell);
```

Может есть более подходящая для этого библиотека?

Comment: Я так понял проблемы получить результат и положит его в ячейку нет, а чтобы заполнить таблицу по столбцу строке думаю поможет эта ссылка https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811161/how-to-fill-a-pdfptable-column-by-column-instead-of-row-by-row-using-itext

Comment: Видел этот пример, но засомневался, что цикл для String [] в моём случае поможет. Попробую...

Comment: Вместо String [] у тебя же свой набор данных, как он должен писаться, одна запись равна одной строке?
Подредач код чтобы работало под твои объекты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Java 8 можно применить цикл для добавления ячеек в таблицу. В этом цикле данные берутся из БД. Для этого используются гетеры, созданные в классе `Message`,  описывающем структуру БД.

```
    for (Message mess : messages) {
        table.addCell(mess.getText());
        table.addCell(mess.getInvid());
        table.addCell(mess.getSn());
        table.addCell(mess.getAuthor());
    }
```